# Caching LiDAR Image Service outside of ArcGIS to send to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, tilemill, lidar, tilecache, image-service

I have very limited programming/coding experience.

We are hosting a number of LiDAR services on ArcGIS Server, and need 24 of these to be cached, from 1:500,000 to 1:4,000.
We initially had published as map services, manually creating cache in ArcGIS after the service was published. However there were blank tiles upon completion (Status read 100%).  We tried publishing the mosaic datasets from the server, from the local desktop, from the NAS... We tried to publish as a cached image service.

We submitted a number of case tickets with Esri and each time they have moved us up to ladder to the next analyst.  The latest response was "No Solution" and suggested to take the open source route to cache our services.  The data itself is fine, and the areas that were covered by the blank tiles cached in ArcGIS are completely visible on the dynamic rendering of the image service.

I need to find a way (outside ArcGIS) to read in a currently published dynamically rendering image service from ArcGIS Server.  I will need to cache this service based on the scale noted above, and save this cache to file location on our NAS to be read in by other applications and users.
I have no idea how arduous a process this will be, nor the requirements to perform such a task.
Apparently it can be done; the image services we host are WMS compatible and support JSON.

I've looked into Tile Mill and MapBox, but honestly wouldn't know where to begin.

If you'd like to look at an example of the image services that need caching, let me know and I can provide a link.

Current version: 
ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

We have also tested it on ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 as we are upgrading our machines as soon as we figure this out. But still no solution with the newer version of ArcGIS for Server

Comment: Out of interest, which version of ArcGIS for Server were you creating those caches in and can I assume you were pushing to the bundled format?  I would like to see a link to the image service please.

Comment: Andre I think I can offer advice but first I need to confirm what you are seeking in terms of cache. There are many meanings of that term, and if I assume the incorrect meaning, we won't get you the correct answer! From the workflow you describe above ("published as map services, manually creating cache in ArcGIS after the service was published" & ref to WMS), I'm thinking you mean a cached version of a hillshade - is that correct? If not, and you are seeking Cached Image Elevation Services (3D surface), you'll need a fundamentally different workflow. Please also let us know what version of Ar

Comment: Chris - thanks - but I tried to "comment" and don't yet have a 50 reputation...

Comment: @Simon I updated the question with version of ArcGIS Server.  Yes we are pushing to the bundled format

Comment: @CodyBenkelman Yes, the services in question here are shaded relief. So essentially just a hillshade with a pansharpening function so there is a color ramp tint on them for aesthetics.

Comment: @Simon   http://lidar.salisbury.edu/arcgis/rest/services/ShadedRelief/MD_baltimore_shadedRelief/ImageServer

Comment: @Simon ^ Here is the dynamically rendered image service that needs to be cached at 1:500,000 through 1:4,000 ^